# how to correctly implement async event handlers in browser

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, events, ecmascript-6

I am struggling with this problem on an older project I have for a while. I also created a [sample repo](https://github.com/rostacik/asyncEventDemo) here but you maybe don't need it.

The problem is, I have more event handlers hooked on same elements or hooked to element up the chain where the event will bubble.

The problem is, that once the code of first handler encounters await (or yield when I build my code with typescript), next handler is fired. How can I synchronize execution to wait until everything in first handler finishes and only then continues to next event handler up the chain?

I saw some samples with "promisification of event emitter", but I am not in control of event object here, since it is created by browser runtime.

Also I have seen some RxJS hints, but could anyone give me a small sample, how he managed to fix the problem?

One small thing - sometimes I also need to await whole execution of another button click that might have chain of its own event handlers.

Comment: Why do you have multiple different event listeners at all when they are that intimately coupled?

Comment: indeed good question. answer is simple, tons of legacy code that I should fix, sir.

Comment: So you are just now introducing asynchronous listeners, or was this simply buggy from the beginning?

Comment: Hi there. A number of folks in our community sometimes say that every time they see gendered assumptions about software engineers, they worry about people feeling excluded. I wonder, could you try to avoid adding male-oriented greetings and pronouns in your posts, so as to make for a more welcoming environment? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One might consider this a hack, but you could build a promise chain on the event object:

```js
function delay(t) {
  return new Promise(resolve => { setTimeout(resolve, t); });
}
function handler(e) {
  e.innerColorChangeDone = Promise.resolve(e.innerColorChangeDone) // might be undefined
    .then(() => delay(100))
    .then(() => {
      this.style.backgroundColor = "#"+Array.from({length:3}, () =>
        Math.round(Math.random()*5+9).toString(16)
      ).join("");
      return delay(100);
    });
}
for (const el of document.getElementsByTagName("div"))
  el.onclick = handler;
```

```css
div {
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid 1px #aaa;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        Click!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The event object is the same, being passed to each of the handlers. If you want to do anything asynchronous that other (later) event handler will need to depend on, store a promise for your result on the event object. Then in the waiting handler, wait for that particular promise. You can also use multiple different promise chains, or ignore the promise if you want something in an outer handler to happen immediately.

In ES8 you might use `async`/`await` like this:

```
function handler(e) {
  e.innerColorChangeDone = (async () => {
    await e.innerColorChangeDone;
    await delay(100);
    this.style.backgroundColor = …
    await delay(100);
  })();
}
```

Comment: thank you sir! working like charm!!! I have iterated to something similar but your example is WAY better! again, thank you!

now the other part of the problem : how could I trigger different element with it's own chain of event handlers hooked to it but await the execution of them all, when handlers return by design void?

it seems I can't pass my event object to HTMLElement.onclick() as parameter, since .onclick() is without any input parameter.

thx

Comment: You can of course [trigger your own events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) (and again, wait for the promise on the event object after the handlers ran), but it sounds like you want to wait for a user to have clicked multiple buttons. For that, you need to maintain some state in your application, you can't do that just with event handlers.

Comment: @rostacik: if this was the answer, or substantially contributed to you finding the answer, consider accepting it. To do that, click on the tick icon to the left of it, so that it is marked as the solution. This has the effect of giving the person who helped you a few reputation points for their time and effort.

Comment: Thanks Bergi! I use the [SO CVR boilerplate list](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/auto-comments/master/sites/stackoverflow.com/questions.md), I should get something including that added.