# Page reload with FormData object?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Somehow my Page reloads as soon as I add following code to my eventlistener of the type submi

```
await fetch('http://localhost:3000/upload', {
    method: 'POST',
    header: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: formData,
});
```

When I remove it, my code continous with the following code but otherwise, it will refresh.

Why is that and what can help here?

```
fourthForm.addEventListener('submit', async function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        
        const username = document.getElementById('username');
        const profileImage = document.getElementById('profilePicture');

        // store image in const. change name of image to date and time + "-" + username
        let image = profileImage.files[0];
        let date = Date.now();
        let ending = image.name.substring(image.name.lastIndexOf('.'), image.name.length);
        let imageName = username.value + ending;
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('image', image, imageName);

        USER = {
            ...USER,
            username: username.value,
            image: date + "_" + imageName
        };

        console.log(USER);

        await fetch('http://localhost:3000/upload', {
            method: 'POST',
            header: {
                'content-type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: formData,
        });

        await fetch('http://localhost:3000/user', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(USER),
        });

        window.location.href = './index.html';
    });
```

This will never get to the /user part. Only if I remove the part mentioned before.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNSRi.png)

This is my console output. Translated:
Navigate to url.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Just tacking on `async` in front of `function` doesn't make the receiving function any more capable of dealing with it. The `submit` event listener on HTMLFormElement is synchronous; it will ignore any asynchronous calls you have in your code.

Comment: See [how to correctly implement async event handlers in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48688136/215552) for a possible workaround.

Comment: I just added my console output in a Screenshot

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be related to async'ness of your callback. Make sure default event doesn't fire before your `.preventDefault`. There is no need to make your callback asynchronous, you can delete all `async` and `await` keywords. I suppose this should work like that:

```js
fourthForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        // store image in const. change name of image to date and time + "-" + username
        let image = profileImage.files[0];
        let date = Date.now();
        let ending = image.name.substring(image.name.lastIndexOf('.'), image.name.length);
        let imageName = username.value + ending;
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('image', image, imageName);

        USER = {
            ...USER,
            username: username.value,
            image: date + "_" + imageName
        };

        console.log(USER);

        fetch('http://localhost:3000/upload', {
            method: 'POST',
            header: {
                'content-type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: formData,
        }).then(() => {
            fetch('http://localhost:3000/user', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(USER),
            }).then(() => {
                window.location.href = './index.html';
            })
        });
    });
```

Also there's no need to select ids with `document.getElementById`. Ids are automatically accessible by there names as JS variables.

Comment: Thank you for the information with the IDs. Thats crazy to know. Thanks. I'm about to try out your solution. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't work too. It reloads the page. And no there is nothing even similar to something that might be something like window.location or else.